# How to use the HWE kernel that is included in ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso?

Tags: server, grub2, kernel, iso

I'm in a situation where I'm adding some new machines to an existing compute cluster installed with 18.04. Unfortunately the disk controller on the new machines isn't recognized by the 4.15 kernel, so I need to switch to the HWE 5.x kernel. Of course I can't do this post-install because I can't install the OS in the first place (it doesn't see any disks).  Much to my surprise I discovered that the HWE linux kernel is already on the current 18.04 ISO, but there doesn't seem to be any way access it, which seems weird; i.e. why is it even there then, if it's not presented as an install option and doesn't appear in the grub menu post install? So, before I go to the trouble of building a new live ISO from scratch, is there any way to activate this option, or better make it the default on installation?

Comment: The current ISO should install the current kernel, that's the whole purpose of point releases. But be aware 18,04 as less than a year of support left, consider upgrading ASAP.

Comment: An upgrade is in the works, but right now people are frantically working on grant research so I need to get them their new machines ASAP. That said, the current ISO installs the 4.15 kernel with no option to install the included 5.x HWE kernel instead.